# Разные списки и открытие

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста Мне надо чтобы при одном списке открывались одни activity, а при другом другие.

**Тут меняется список:**

```
     package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

        import android.support.v7.app.AppCom

patActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

        String[] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
        ListView listView1;
        String[] arro;
        List<String> adapterList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

            arro = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1ob);
            arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);

            adapterList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

            listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

            // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapterList);

            // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            setMyAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void setMyAdapter(final ArrayAdapter adapter){
            ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    adapterList.clear();
                    if (isChecked) {
                        adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));

                    } else {
                        adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arro));
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если меняется только информация, то может стоит просто менять данные, а не скрывать listview?

Comment: Мне надо как-то так сделать чтобы при одном списке открывались такие-то activity, а при другом другие. Это реально реализовать не знаю что делать.

Comment: Как сделать чтобы при одном списки одни активити открывались не важно какие, а при другом другие.

Comment: проще всего использовать два фрагмента, в каждом свой список. по переключению togglebutton, которая находится в хост- активити менять их

Comment: Буду пробовать.

Comment: А как их менять?

Comment: А можно же вкладки использовать

Comment: Вы говорите о активити во множественном числе. Что должны показывать эти активити? Если структура разметки и логика действий в вызванной активити после нажатия айтемов списка одинаковые, то нужна только одна активити, в которую при клике на айтем нужно передавать только контент (содержимое виджетов) для этой позиции списка

Comment: Вроде бы так, как вы говорите.